# Show a function is not continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

let $g(x) = x - \lfloor{x}\rfloor$ and I want to show that the function is not continuous.

I want to use this definition im pretty sure:
 "For every open set U in $R$, $f^{-1}$ U is open"

But I am struggling to find the inverse where it is closed, maybe something to do with the integers all being 0? Any suggestions welcome, Thank you!

Comment: $f^{-1}(\Bbb{R})=[0,1)$ which is not open.

Comment: $f^{-1}(\Bbb R)=\Bbb R$ !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** consider $U =(-1/2, 1/2)$, then $f^{-1}(U) = \bigcup\limits_{n\in\Bbb Z} [n, n+1/2)$ is not open.

Comment: I see, but why is $f^{-1}$ (U) not open?

Comment: it is not open, because $0$ is in it but none of the sets $(-r,r)$ for $r>0$

Comment: also, if the downvoter could comment it would be nice.

Comment: Sorry, still  bit lost. What is r?

Comment: it is any positive number. if $V$ is an open set (in a metric space) and $x\in V$ you can find $r>0$ for which $\{y: d(x,y)<r\}\subset V$ (this is the very definition of an open set).

Comment: I did not downvote, but it is pretty evident that your answer wont be helpful for a beginner, which the OP obviosuly seem to be.

Comment: I do not see the problem: OP explicitely ask to use the general definition of continuity, and it is a good way to learn how to use it.

Comment: Could you give a specific example just to help me understand a bit better, something more simple. I do not see what the 0 has to do with it being not open. Is that the boundary point that is contained?

Comment: If the set contains some of the boundary points, but not all of them, is the set not open. And is that why we are focused on the 0?

Comment: a simplier example: $[0,1)$. 0 is contained but you can't find a neighborhood of 0 contained in  $[0,1)$. We can focus on any integer, it would work the same way. Also, note that a set is open iff it contains NONE of the  boundaty points, not all of them!

Comment: So U = $R$ and the $f^{-1}$ (U) = $[0,1)$ ?

Comment: So U = [0,1) and what would its inverse be then? All the reals? And  the [0,1) is not open?

Comment: We want U to be open and $f^{-1}$ to be not open?

Comment: AHA! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: yes, so that the definition of continuity fails, in particular it is discontinuous

Comment: exactly. because we want to prove that the proposition "$\forall U$ open set, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open" fails.

Comment: can you explain why the inverse image is [0,1)?

Comment: actually $f^{-1}(\Bbb R)=\Bbb R$... look at my answer for a true statement !

Comment: So I cannot say that $f^{-1}$ ($R$) = [0,1)?

Comment: no, this is not true. $f^{-1}(R) = R$, always !

Comment: but above you say: "read again my comment. let U=R, then f−1(U)=[0,1) is not open. –  mookid 13 mins ago"

Comment: yes, I was wrong. look again at my answer!

Comment: which answer? what U do we want and what inverse do we want?

Comment: take $u = (-1/2,1/2)$. look at the answer, not the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Take $x_n =\frac{1}{n} $. Cleary, $x_n \to 0 $. If $f$ were continuous at $0$, then $f(x_n) = \frac{1}{n} - 1 \to f(0) = 0 $. But, $f(x_n) \to -1 $. hence, $f$ cannot be continuous at the origin.

Comment: you do not use the general definition of OP.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is using the following fact:

> If $X$ and $Y$ are metrizable, then $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous if and only if for every convergent sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\rightarrow x$, the sequence $\{f(x_n)\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $f(x)$.

Then take any monotonically decreasing function that approaches an integer and derive a contradiction.